# How can I change the status with setState function in a component that extends another in React

Tags: reactjs, components, state, extends, setstate

when i use steState function in MyComponent it does nothing and in console log the original state?

This is my code of BaseComponent:

```
export class BaseComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      foo: 'bar'
    }
    this.setMyState();
  }
  render() { return (<div></div>); }
}
```

And this is the extended component code:

```
import { BaseComponent } from 'path/to/BaseComponent';

export class MyComponent extends BaseComponent {
  setMyState () {
    console.warn('MyComponent --->', this.state);  // Return {foo: bar}
    this.setState({ foo: 'koala' });
    console.warn('MyComponent --->', this.state);   // Return {foo: bar}
  }
}
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you're having isn't because the `setMyState()` isn't properly modifying your state but rather because the react `this.setState()` function is actually async so the new state value isn't guaranteed to be set on the next line when you `console.warn()`.

[See this link for a more detailed explanation about the async nature of `this.setState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Here is an excerpt from the React Docs that explains it.

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to
>   update the component. For better perceived performance, React may
>   delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React
>   does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, i didn't think about the async problem of JS, but if I put the console.warn into the callback or (more brutally) in a setTimeout() I aspect that che result change but it isn't so.